# Removing entirely duplicate rows from all tables in an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a query that will remove duplicates from a table, while at the same time being column-agnostic, so it can be iterated over all tables in the database.

Currently, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM EXISTING_TABLE;
TRUNCATE EXISTING_TABLE;
INSERT INTO EXISTING_TABLE (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TMP_TABLE);
DROP TMP_TABLE;
```

Is this a good way to do it? Is there a way to do this in-place?

Comment: This implies that that you have no PK at all in any of your tables, sounds weird and even terrible

Comment: It makes sense to not have a PK in our case, since the tables are generated, and sometimes modified, dynamically. Adding PK management to the system would simply be just too much work for us.

Furthermore, having duplicates in the database is not that big of a deal for us, since the data are being used to create plots. A duplicate data point will not show up on that plot. But since we got rid of a bug that caused duplicates to sometimes be inserted, we would still like to remove them now.

Comment: Then your approach should work

Comment: I do go with ctas with select distinct,drop original table and rename temp to original

Answer (score 1):

You can directly delete the duplicates in the original table rather than creating a new temp table and inserting back again.

```
DELETE * FROM EXISTING_TABLE where row_id not in
(select max(row_id) from EXISTING_TABLE group by col1);  -- Include any one column in group by
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query for removing duplicate rows in table through self join**

```
DELETE FROM XXPWC_TEST -- Assume table name XXPWC_TEST
WHERE HEADER_ID IN (
SELECT A.HEADER_ID 
FROM XXPWC_TEST A
    ,XXPWC_TEST B
WHERE 1=1
AND A.H_NAME = B.H_NAME -- Join duplicate column name
AND A.H_NAME2 = B.H_NAME2 -- Join duplicate column name
AND A.HEADER_ID > B.HEADER_ID -- Primary key
);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The query should **not** require knowledge of the columns in the database table. It appears that your query **does** require such knowledge. Hence I would say that it is not suitable for the OP.